# Select only direct descendants from table with a materialized path

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, materialized-path-pattern

I'm trying to use the 'Materialized Path' pattern for storing a directory structure in a SQLite database on an Android app. My single table has a primary key field that is the file path, like this:

```
PATH(PK)
/sdcard/foo
/sdcard/bar
/sdcard/foo/music
/sdcard/foo/films
/sdcard/bar/photos
```

I would like to get a list of the direct children of the /sdcard directory. I know how to get ALL the (indirect) descendants of /sdcard using this SQL:

```
WHERE PATH LIKE '/sdcard/%'
```

which returns all rows. But what is the SQL for getting just the top level children, so only returning:

```
/sdcard/foo
/sdcard/bar
```

The answer to this question might provide insight but my SQL isn't strong enough to understand 'The Scrum Meister's response:
[Selecting based on path in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337560/selecting-based-on-path-in-mysql)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
WHERE PATH LIKE '/sdcard/%' and PATH not like '/sdcard/%/%'
```

Comment: That seems like a brilliant and simple answer. I'll give it a try and if it works I'll mark this as the answer.